# "Unable to play track - the file can not be found" on Sonos

Tags: sonos

Sonos seems to struggle with redirects on occasion. I'm not sure what's special about some redirects vs. others (same environment), but it works ~50% of the time reproducibly and consistently.

If I request the HEAD of the file and get the redirect and pass that onto Sonos it works just fine. The only problem is that now the CDN delivers the best location to my server, not the client as would be ideal.

Here's a URL that fails until you give it the final redirected URL:  https://archive.org/download/gd1976-08-02.fob.singer.motb-1.81456.sbeok.flac16/gd76-08-02d1t06.mp3

Comment: Could you try to playback a track that you know will fail, and when it does, submit diagnostics (https://sonos.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/142/~/submit-system-diagnostics) right away. Once you've done that, post the diag number you get back here.

Comment: @MattWelch 7353503

Comment: @MattWelch here's another given a slightly different context: 7353525

Comment: I didn't see anything specifically related to redirect problems in your diags. Is there a specific reason you think redirects are the culprit? Regardless, please give our customer care folks a call, as they mentioned some networking issues visible in the diags that bear some investigation. 1 (800) 680-2345